# Урон в Unity2D мечом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичёк в Unity и в целом в c#, хотелсь бы узнать, как можно реализовать урон с помощью меча в 2д игре, смотрел гайд на ютубе, там показан меч перса как отдельный предмет, то есть, когда он касается врага, то урон отнимается, это я понял, только я скачал спрайты, где меч не отделен от персонажа, можно ли это как-то реализовать? Также, пытался для начал сделать через OnCollisionEnter2D, но когда проигрывается анимация, то не регестриурется прикосновения меча к врагу.

Comment: В анимации коллизии не будет, потому что анимация не движение физики.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить странный способ, но рабочий. Создайте пустой спрайт привяжите его к вашему герою и создайте для него boxcollider2d по размеру меча. Если враг касается пустого спрайта, то наносится урон.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую